# Pandas create a column iteratively - increasing after specific threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple table which the datetime is formatted correctly on.

| Datetime | Diff |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 12:02:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 12:04:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 12:010:00 | 6 |
| 2021-01-01 12:020:00 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 12:022:00 | 2 |

I would like to add a label/batch name which increases when a specific threshold/cutoff time is the difference. The output (with a threshold of diff > 7) I am hoping to achieve is:

| Datetime | Diff | Batch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 0 | A |
| 2021-01-01 12:02:00 | 2 | A |
| 2021-01-01 12:04:00 | 2 | A |
| 2021-01-01 12:010:00 | 6 | A |
| 2021-01-01 12:020:00 | 10 | B |
| 2021-01-01 12:022:00 | 2 | B |

Batch doesn't need to be 'A','B','C' - probably easier to increase numerically.

I cannot find a solution online but I'm assuming there is a method to split the table on all values below the threshold, apply the batch label and concatenate again. However I cannot seem to get it working.

Any insight appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Batch'] = df['Datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds().gt(7*60) \
                            .cumsum().add(65).apply(chr)
print(df)

# Output:
             Datetime  Diff Batch
0 2021-01-01 12:00:00     0     A
1 2021-01-01 12:02:00     2     A
2 2021-01-01 12:04:00     2     A
3 2021-01-01 12:10:00     6     A
4 2021-01-01 12:20:00    10     B
5 2021-01-01 12:22:00     2     B
```

**Update**

> For a side question: apply(char) goes through A-Z, what method would you use to achieve AA, AB for batches greater than 26

Try something like this:

```
# Adapted from openpyxl
def chrext(i):
    s = ''
    while i > 0:
        i, r = divmod(i, 26)
        i, r = (i, r) if r > 0 else (i-1, 26)
        s += chr(r-1+65)
    return s[::-1]

df['Batch'] = df['Datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds().gt(7*60) \
                            .cumsum().add(1).apply(chrext)
```

For demonstration purpose, if you replace 1 by 27:

```
>>> df
             Datetime  Diff Batch
0 2021-01-01 12:00:00     0    AA
1 2021-01-01 12:02:00     2    AA
2 2021-01-01 12:04:00     2    AA
3 2021-01-01 12:10:00     6    AA
4 2021-01-01 12:20:00    10    AB
5 2021-01-01 12:22:00     2    AB
```

Comment: Thank you for this - that is fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. For a side question: apply(char) goes through A-Z, what method would you use to achieve AA, AB for batches greater than 26.

Comment: @withayk. I updated my answer based on your comment. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 3):

Since True and False values represent 1 and 0 when summed, you can use this to create a cumulative sum on a boolean column made by `df.Diff > 7`:

`df['Batch'] = (df.Diff > 7).cumsum()`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a custom group that has the properties you want. After you group the values your batch is simply group number. You don't have to use groupby with only an existing column. You can give a custom index and it is really powerful.

```
from datetime import timedelta

df['batch'] == df.groupby(((df['Datetime'] - df['Datetime'].min()) // timedelta(minutes=7)).ngroup()
```